# Server automatic reconnect?

Tags: networking

I'm trying to setup a Ubuntu hardware firewall (just for fun :D) and I was wondering if Ubuntu's network scripts could automatically reconnect to the wired interface (eth0) when the connection is dropped?

My ISP's modem is pretty bad and requires a reset once in a while. It's annoying to go to basement with a keyboard and blindly login and type `/etc/init.d/networking restart`.

Comment: What version of the server do you have?

Comment: Ubuntu 11.04 x86

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at [cron](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cron) and [crontab](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/crontab). What you need to do is create a script that you can insert into `cron` that...

- checks every x minutes if the connection is down.

  - if is not down do nothing.
  - if it is down reconnect.

Example of such a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

IP_ADRESS=192.168.1.1
( ! ping -c1 $IP_ADRESS >/dev/null 2>&1 ) && service network restart >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Put this in a scrip (set the IP adress to what you want to check), make it executable with

```
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/check_network
```

and run the script from crontab. You can edit this line into it with the command `crontab -e`:

`*/2 * * * * root /usr/local/bin/check_network`

- */2 makes it check 30 times an hour.

Comment: Rinzwind, this works very well, even on my Pentium III :D. Although not directly related to this question, is there a way to restart only one interface? I'd rather not have the entire LAN go down when only the modem fails.

Comment: I can't test it right now... try `sudo /sbin/ifconfig eth0 up`

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to give a look to the following two packages:

**`ifplugd`**

```
Package: ifplugd
Description: configuration daemon for ethernet devices
 ifplugd is a daemon which will automatically configure your ethernet device
 when a cable is plugged in and automatically de-configure it if the cable is
 pulled out. This is useful on laptops with onboard network adapters, since it
 will only configure the interface when a cable is really connected.  Features
 include:
 .
  * syslog support
  * Multiple ethernet interface support
  * Uses Debian's native ifup/ifdown programs
  * Small executable size and memory footprint
  * Option to beep when the cable is unplugged or plugged
  * Option to beep when the interface configuration succeeds or fails
  * Can be configured to ignore short unplugged or plugged periods
  * Configure WLAN devices (on detecting a successful association to an AP)
  * Supports SIOCETHTOOL, SIOCGMIIREG and SIOCDEVPRIVATE for getting link status
  * Compatibility mode for network devices which do not support cable detection
```

**`netplug`**

```
Package: netplug
Description: network link monitor daemon
 This daemon monitors the link status of network cards and configures
 the network on plug- and un-plug-events.
 .
 It's similar to ifplugd, but uses NETLINK instead of regularly polling
 the link status. This improves power-consumption with laptops, but does
 not work with all network card.
```

I have used in the past the first of this, and it works well on cable unplug and replug, but I don't know if it work also in your situation that seems a little bit different.

Comment: That sounds like exactly what I'm looking for! I'll test it out and report back.

Comment: When I get syn flooded and my wireless drops these 2 do not respond to it ;)

Comment: Netplug and ifplugd both successfully disables and reenables the network card, but after it's reenabled, there's no network access at all. I can't ping the modem from the server and I can't ping the server from the LAN.

Comment: Dear friends, this was a only a tentitive suggestion yet to verify, because I don't have the same problem.